# How to pass array from pug to pug mixin?

Tags: html, arrays, pug, interpolation

I have a pug template with an array in it, that I want to pass over to a mixin used to populate some schema.org (json) markup.

Here's the code:

profile.pug

```
include ../components/bio-seo

- var person = {}
- person.title = "Name, title of person"
- person.url = "https://page.url..."
- person.image = "https://images.url..."
- person.links = ["https://link.one...","https://link.two..."]

+bio-seo(person)
```

And then in the mixin, I have:

mixin.pug

```
mixin bio-seo(person)
  title= title
  link(rel='canonical', href=url)

  script(type="application/ld+json").
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Person",
      "image": "#{person.image}",
      "url": "#{person.url}",
      "sameAs": #{person.links}
    }
```

Everything works great, except the array of 'sameAs' links. After compiling, I get:

```
"sameAs": https://link.one,https://link.two
```

Instead of what I need, which is

```
"sameAs": ["https://link.one","https://link.two"]
```

Comment: This all lands in the head of the HTML document, by the way.

Comment: `"sameAs": [!{person.links.map(link => '"' + link.toString() + '"')}]` That seems to work, but.... dam!! Do I really need all that?

Comment: ^ That's the most concise way I know how to do it

Comment: Why can't it just be `!{person.links}`? Or even `person.links`?

Comment: `!{...}` is unescaped string interpolation, and it just prints the values of whatever it contains as a string. Array markup (brackets, quotes) isn't part of the value of the array.

Whenever I have to use js like this, I like to write it as a function using a code block in a separate `.pug` file. That way you can just include your functions file and keep your pug cleaner by writing something like `printArray(person.links)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `JSON.stringify` in conjuction with [Unescaped interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped) `!{}` to get your array as a string:

```
"sameAs": !{JSON.stringify(person.links)}
```